# match first and last character with known number of inbetween letters

Tags: regex, notepad++

there is a text file with words.
so if a word has 5 letters and the first letter is a and the last letter is s i want to match all the words that follow that pattern.

```
^a.???.s$
```

this doesn't seem to work

( i'm testing in notepad++ )

any ideas what the correct regex would be ?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
^a.{3}s$ // .{3} means, match any character exactly 3 times.
```

Which is basically the same as:

```
^a...s$ // . means, match any character
```

Comment: thanks, this seems to work, though i don't understand why there is a dot before, but not after!

Comment: @MIrrorMirror Why would you expect a dot after? Help me understand your line of reasoning and I'll try to elaborate for you.

Comment: probably because i'm a newbie at regexes. i thought the logic should be firstchar . { number_of_inbetween } . lastchar where the . plays the "concat" role.

Comment: @MIrrorMirror [Nicholas' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091899/match-first-and-last-character-with-known-number-of-inbetween-letters#14091984) is actually much better. I think you should go with that one.

Comment: @MIrrorMirror O, I see. No, a dot `.` simply means *any character*. There's not really a concept of concatenation in regular expressions. But like I said, Nicholas' answer is much more robust, as it makes sure each character between `a` and `s` is actually a letter, not just *any* character (whitespace, numbers, etc.) and that `a` and `s` are found at word boundary by using `\b`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match all occurrences you should do:

```
/\ba[a-z]{3}s\b/
```

For non-latin characters:

```
/\ba\S{3}s\b/
```

Comment: Yeah, that's actually much more robust. I was being sloppy.

Comment: thank you. i've no idea what those \b do, however doesn't seem to work as the words are not in latin chars.

Comment: I added an option for non-latin characters.
`\b` is a word boundry, so that means it could be a space before and after or not. `\S` means everything that isn't a space/new line etc.